# How do you kill DAYZ zombies punching them?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I have attempted many times and normally they go down and after some seconds they come up again.

Only one time I have been able to kill them so.

It's necessary to click the middle mouse button when they are down?

Can be a issue on my laptop being very laggy on dayz ? thanks

Comment: Just keep punching their face, it knocks them down. Same happens if you do it to a player, if you punch the face you can knock them down. Ofcourse it does little damage, but just keep punching, you'll get there eventually :p

Comment: Your best bet is an axe or a hoe for melee. One hit to the head and they're dead. If you don't have an axe or a hoe then your best bet is to avoid or run..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Punching does little damage compared to other weapons. Its main strength is its stopping power, able to stop a zombie in its tracks quickly. However it will take many punches to actually *kill* a zombie. This is just another reason to try your best to avoid zombies, they're not the easiest thing to kill.

The only real advice I can offer you is to aim for the head, it will be easier to knock them down and does more damage. Other than that, there isn't any "secret" strategy aside from persistence.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot of punches to kill a zombie, normally I will knock them down with a few punches to the head then I keep punching them in the head while they are knocked out. If they get back up repeat the process again. You never have to knock them out more than twice if you keep punching them while they are knocked out.